# Frontend framework change

Tags: reactjs, angular, ember.js, frameworks

We are a small company, using emberjs as the main frontend framework for our projects. The frontend architect sticks to it like liquid glue sticks to paper, because he doesn't know any other frameworks. The main reason that is forced is the slogan: 'convention over configuration'. And there are reasons like emberjs is faster in larger scale applications.
Anyone can reason pro-contra for emberjs, angular, react etc.. (hopefully someone who knows all of them, at least emberjs, and another)? We are having meeting sessions about this, where junior frontend devs try to convince the architect about the other frameworks. In my opinion this should not be a technical issue, all of the frameworks are capable of developing 'larger scale' applications. The real reason should be the recruiting, we would find react/angular devs more easily.
Thanks

Comment: Users on Stackoverflow are focused on solving specific technical questions. You're better off asking in forums or social media boards.

Comment: Read it: https://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newTMC_5W.htm

Comment: This website is to help with specific, technical problems. Your question is somewhat subjective and I think you answer is easy to find online.

Comment: I agree with Michael, I bet there is a StackExchange website that is more suited for this question, but StackOverflow is a good way to reach the javascript devs community

Comment: This question has been moved to SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/432803/frontend-framework-change/432815#432815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same situation and managed to migrate to react+redux toolkit+nextjs.

The way I started my introduction is by explaining what is react. React is a rendering engine. I compared it to glimmer components and ember components. I then explained that most of our components were ember components wich are deprecated and need to be migrated anyway

I then explained that we could just live with ember data, ember cli and react.

Then I showed why ember cli was old and there was this new cool kid embroider that we will need to migrate in the future. I explained what was embroider and how it compared with nextjs. I pointed out that I had experience with react and nextjs but not with embroider.

Then I pitched that Ember Data along with nextjs and react was a viable solution. I also showed that the standard stack with nextjs and react was to use in place of ember data: redux toolkit (you could choose react-query depending on your needs)

At the end of this meeting, people were excited but still had questions.
I then had to do different presentations and discussions about architecture and costs. I produced swot analysis, risk analysis, benchmarks on component libraries (we went with zendesk garden), cost of development per feature..

It's a long process but if you take time to discuss. Remove any passion from the discussions and at the end focus on reducing costs, you'll get your migration.. and yeah the fact we were struggling to recruit ember experts helped with my arguments :D

I should write a blog post about that xD

PS: regarding "convention over configuration", you can find this concept applied by nextjs and redux toolkit